# How to Create an Animated Determinate Circular Progress Indicator?

Tags: flutter, animation

How to create something like that in Flutter:

[image]

I tried the following code, but it's drawn without being animated.

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
  value: 0.50,
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.pink),
)
```

Comment: For it to be animated you have to change the value periodically over time, it may start with 0 and every 100 milliseconds increases by 0.1 till it reaches 0.5.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use an [ImplicityAnimatedWidget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ac6ea52b3795b8b1fbe9b542b9e9f0e98c25124f/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart#L274) such as `TweenAnimationBuilder`

Example:

This will animate over 3.5 seconds and the progress will start from 0% to 100%, you can tweak those in the `begin:`, `end:` parameters

```dart
TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
    tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1),
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3500),
    builder: (context, value, _) => CircularProgressIndicator(value: value),
)
```

You can also use [`AnimatedBuilder`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d19c44344b1bfc11ec9c06875c34dfca3c177d66/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart#L1092) to take more control over the animation